# If an entity's primary key is composed of only one column, is it automatically in 2NF?

Tags: database, database-normalization

When my instructor taught my SQL class about 2NF, they mentioned that it's violated if there's partial dependency - that is, when a table has a composite key and a non-key column depends only on one of the keys, and not all of the columns that comprise the PK.

If there's an entity with a single-columned PK, and there's a non-key attribute that does not depend on this PK, does it mean that it's in 2NF because the entity does not have a composite key and partial dependency is not possible, and would therefore never be violated (an attribute is only either dependent or not dependent on the PK)?

Thank you!

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial . Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. Quote the definitions, theorems & algorithms you are relying on. All the steps are also SO faqs. PS Asking about correctness of guesses while not understanding is not helpful. Say where you're stuck applying definitions/algorithms. PS PKs & entities don't matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when a 1NF table has no composite candidate keys is it in 2NF?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10940117/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly not an expert on this subject but to quote GeeksforGeeks:

"Second Normal Form applies to relations with composite keys, that is, relations with a primary key composed of two or more attributes. **A relation with a single-attribute primary key is automatically in at least 2NF.**" (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/second-normal-form-2nf/)

So, at least according to them, the answer is yes.

Comment: The quote is wrong, although that's a common misconception. [when a 1NF table has no composite candidate keys is it in 2NF?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10940117/3404097)  However the question is not phrased using proper terms & is garbled & the 2nd paragraph "if" is trivially logically true & its "because" wrong because every attribute is functionally determined by a PK, so it can't be the case that "there's a non-key attribute that does not depend on this PK".