# How to Normalize A Table Which Has A Foreign Key

Tags: database, entity-relationship, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I'm trying to normalize a table and I have some difficulties. In my table, I have 3 attributes which are

User(**Username**, Password, *Employee_ID*)

Now I'm trying to normalize this table. First as far as I know I need to determine the Functional Dependencies

Username->Password,Employee_ID

Employee_ID-> Username,Password

So there are 2 candidate keys yet something does not fit. So here is my first question comes

If we have a primary key in a table, shouldn't we directly say that that table is in the second form since a single attribute is a candidate key? Also if we have a primary key and a foreign key in a table, how do we normalize this table?

I thought creating another table as a composite entity which includes Username and Employee_ID, would be logical but I'm not sure whether it is the solution or not.

Edit: Also additionaly I need to determine the functional dependency yet here the only ones that I could find are the ones that I wrote above. So from here if this table is not in the second form also I need to demonstrate the partial dependency yet I cannot find that too.

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial & you have shown no research. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following a reference with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. Quote the definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you are relying on. All the steps are also SO faqs.

Comment: What is your 1 question? PS "Normalize" alone doesn't mean any particular thing. "as far as I know" typically means, I don't know; what did you do to find out? "since a single attribute is a CK" You likely mean, since every CK is a single attribute. [It is a myth that it implies 2NF.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10940117/3404097) And a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers.

Comment: Determining CKs & NFs requires finding all the FDs with a relation variable's attributes that hold & don't hold. Get definitions of FD, CK & NFs. Here you seem to start with some table membership criterion & 1st seek all FDs that hold but are stuck in that process or stuck finding that process. Where exactly? What does your textbook & SO & other research & the definitions for FD & for a FD holding say about finding them? PS When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.