# there are two candidate keys but Primary key is not a composite key then the given relation is in 2nf or not?

Tags: database, relational-database, rdbms, database-normalization

Customer table having attributes (id, name, email, password, mobile). There are two candidate keys one is **id**, and the other is **email**, but the primary key is only **id**.
[customer_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uycK.jpg)

Comment: Why would or wouldn't it be? What does that CK situation have to do with 2NF? What are the definitions of those terms & where do you get stuck applying them? [ask] [Help] PS Are you asking about that table value, or about a variable that can hold that value? PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. PS [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [What is the policy here on homework?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18242/266284)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normal forms - 2nd vs 3rd - is the difference just composite keys? non trivial dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474203/normal-forms-2nd-vs-3rd-is-the-difference-just-composite-keys-non-trivial-d)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [when a 1NF table has no composite candidate keys is it in 2NF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10936387/3404097) It is a common misconception that all CKs simple implies 2NF. PS You say there are 2 simple CKs, but you do not say what other CKs or FDs there are or aren't. So if you're trying to ask that question, you aren't. PS CKs & FKs matter to DB normalization to higher NFs. PKs do not. One CK can be called PK. That has nothing to do with normalization.