# attribute partially depends on a candidate key but the answer says the relation is in 3NF

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf, candidate-key

> The relation R(ABCD) has the following non-trivial FDs that hold:
> { A -> B ; B -> A ; A -> D ; D -> B }
>
> What is the highest normal form of R?

Since A -> B is extraneous, I removed it to simplify things.
The remaining  set of FDs which I believe is also a cover: { B -> A ; A -> D ; D -> B }

By calculating the closures, I got:
{A}+ = {B}+ = {D}+ = ABD.

Since C is not present in any FDs, if I want to find a key, I would have to add C to {A}, {B} and {C}. With that in mind, I got AC, BC, and DC as candidate keys as {AC}+ = {BC}+ = {DC}+ = ABCD.

With those candidate keys and the FDs, for example, A -> B, B would partially depend on AC since this implies B depends on A, not AC - the key.

If this is true, R is not 2NF because 2NF does not allow partial dependency on the candidate keys.

The answer given is that R is in 3NF, which confuses me because 3NF requires the Relation to be in 2NF first.

My question is: is the Relation's highest NF is 3NF? If so, what is wrong in my reasoning?

Edit:
After revise the definition of Partial Dependency and conditions of 2NF in my lecture slides, they are as such:

"Partial dependency - when a non-key attribute is determined by a part, but not the whole, of a COMPOSITE primary key."

"2NF: A relation R is in second normal form (2NF) if and only if it is in 1NF and every non-key attribute is fully dependent on the primary key
"

As I mentioned above, AC, BC and DC are candidate keys, so A, B and D are key-attributes because they belong to a key.

While B is indeed partially depending on AC because of the FD: A -> B, B is a key-attribute so it does not violate the second condition of 2NF because it only mentions non-key attributes, there is C, but C is not included in the FDs. So R is indeed in 2NF, the same reasoning applies for B and D. Are my reasoning correct?

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must be given. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53386492/3404097)

Comment: What is your (1 specific researched non-duplicate) question? Your post had a lot of questions that seemed to be part of a chain of reasoning & didn't have a clear final question. I edited. To ask whether your reasoning is correct then just give the reasoning in clear small clearly justified steps referring to a competent reference/textbook. Right now you do not quote definitions of partial FD or 2NF & clearly use them in your reasoning. You also don't say that your set of FDs is a closure, which it needs to be for the assignment to be answerable, or show how you used that in your reasoning.

Comment: [Partial Dependency (Databases)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25827210/3404097) [Normal forms - 2nd vs 3rd - is the difference just composite keys? non trivial dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27504915/3404097)

Comment: "R is not 2NF because 2NF does not allow partial dependency on the candidate keys" No. Again: "Right now you do not quote definitions of partial FD or 2NF & clearly use them in your reasoning." PS "You also don't say that your set of FDs is a closure, which it needs to be for the assignment to be answerable, or show how you used that in your reasoning."

Comment: "since this implies B depends on A, not AC - the key" No. B depends on A, but it also depends on AC--it has to, AC is a CK, which by definition determines all attributes. What you had before was correct--B is partially determined by AC. And your reasoning is, ... but A is a proper/smaller subset of AC which is a CK. But then you don't quote &  use a definition of 2NF.

Comment: Again: You need to say that the ORIGINAL set of FDs is a cover. I already told you why. If you don't know it's a cover, the assignment doesn't make sense & your reasoning about a cover is wrong & you need to tell the person who gave you the assignment that it doesn't make sense.

Comment: "I got AC, BC, and DC as candidate keys as {AC}+ = {BC}+ = {DC}+ = ABCD." You don't explain how/why you got them. But you can't because you didn't get them that way, you got the CKs from (correctly) adding C to  {A}, {B} & {D}. If you would clearly say how you get things with justification referring to your references then you would not write these wrong things. And as long as you do not do that then an answer to your question is just a description of the 1st thing you write that's wrong & if it isn't justified clearly we can only show it's wrong, not what's wrong with your reasoning/beliefs.

Comment: About the  term "cover": I dont think I have heard this term, I don't find it when I look it up in my lecture slides and also in my book "A First Course In Database Systems" by Jeffrey D. Ullman and Jennifer Widom. The closest I can find in the book is "basis". Bases represent the full set of FD's for a relation, it contains FDs with singleton right sides; if any FD removed from the basis, it is no longer a basis; If for any FD in basis we remove one or more attributes from the left side of the FDs, the result is no longer a basis. Is basis aligned with minimal cover?

Comment: "the full set of FD's for a relation" That is its closure, the closure of some cover. "it contains FDs with singleton right sides" That would be some kind of canonical minimal/irreducible cover. Which edition of A First Course? I have 3rd/2008. It uses closure. It defines basis set of a set. So that is, cover of a set. (We often say cover when we mean cover of a closure, where the set it's a closure of is a cover.) So a basis for a closure is a cover. Then it defines minimal basis of a schema,  normally called a canonical (minimal) cover. It uses relation for relation schema or variable.

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. [When is "EDIT"/"UPDATE" appropriate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/266284) Please ask exactly 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. PS "Partial dependency - when a non-key attribute is determined by a part, but not the whole, of a COMPOSITE primary key." No. And I said why it can't be "not the whole" before your last edit. Also wrong is "COMPOSITE ": https://stackoverflow.com/a/10940117/3404097. Also wrong are the "PK"s. Quote & credit a (good) published reference/textbook.